# oracle apex tooltip on report region with different values

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an APEX Region, all columns of which are standard report columns. Is it possible to display a tool-tip on mouse over of a particular cell of the report?

I have 3 diff values for tat column it has to display different tooltip for all 3.

Ex: Column having values like aaa bbb ccc

if move mouse to aaa then tooltip text should be "xxx", if bbb then tooltip text should be "yyy", if ccc then tooltip text should be "zzz".

how can i perform this for column in regions.

Comment: please read the text associated with the apex-code tag. It has nothing to do with Oracle APEX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this by using the global HTML [title](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Globale_Attribute/title) attribute by:

- adding a hidden column (called "TOOLTIP" here) to your report that contains your tool-tip text for each row
- and setting the HTML expression at "ColumnFormatting" => "HTML Expression" for the displayed column (called "DISPLAY" here) to:

  ```
  <span title="#TOOLTIP#">#DISPLAY#'</span>
  ```

On hover of the text in your displayed column you should now see your tool-tip text.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example based on Scott's schema. The idea is: display DEPTNO from the EMP table, but - when you put mouse over it - display DNAME from the DEPT table.

```
select EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       JOB,
       '<a title="' || d.dname || '">' || E.DEPTNO || '</a>' AS DEPTNO
  from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
```

Comment: I need to use tooltip on mouse over. So if i need to dispaly text of the column itseld on which mouse is hovering, say here if its DNAME that should show when mouse is on DNAME, query would be -- select EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       JOB,
       '<a title="' || d.dname || '">' || D.DNAME || '</a>' AS DNAME
  from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno   --?